# How to change add to cart button styles in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

Please help me. New to magento.  I need to change a default add to cart button style. So what should i do? please help step by step. i am a beginner.

Comment: Its so helpful . Its working fine. Thanks for tutorial. but i need ur help always... please send your blog or email anything else to share.. kindly help me. Thanks advance

Comment: I download and install a bootstrap from this site ( http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/ ). And i place this my custom template os css, js. Now i am seeing my website is not responsive. what should i do for responsive my template. where i need to include the bootstap file.. Please guide  me

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to magento, You have to learn a lot in this.. I will simply tell you the steps to solve your problem but you have to know each step we make.  In magento, go to this path, `magento/app/design/frontend/default/default/` Now you can see only two folders ie., etc and locale. and now go to this path `magento/app/design/frontend/base/default.` Here you can see the same folders as there in the above path with extra two folders. Copy the template and layout folders and paste them in the first path ie., `magento/app/design/frontend/default/default/`.

Now go to the path `magento/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml.` In the line no. 35, you can see code for att-to-cart button. Now modify this step as below

```
<div class="add-to-cart"><div class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><a><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/add-to-cart.png')?>" alt="Add To Cart" /></a></div></div>
```

Now you need to add your image in the following path, magento/skin/frontend/default/default/images  Here add your image. Dont forget to modify your image name in the code. Now you can see the result. If not, get back to me.